# Retrieve variable values from var file in ansible playbook

Tags: variables, ansible

Need some help to retrieve child values from var file.

Below is my var file

```
api_user: root
api_password: !vault |
          $ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.2;AES256;isi33835326238346338613761366531376662613865376263656262
          6138
Huston:
  onefs_host: 10.88.55.00

Phoenix:
  onefs_host: 10.76.52.01
```

Below is my playbook

```
---
- name: isi_increase
  hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars_files:
         - isilonvars.yml

  tasks:
    - name: Print
      debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ Huston.onefs_host }}"
          - "{{ api_user }}"
          - "{{ api_password }}"
```

This code works perfectly

TASK [Print] ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
"msg": [
"10.88.55.00",
"root",
"Sh00tm3!"
]
}

But as per my requirement i have to retrieve onefs_host IP as per location in my playbook. I am using  extra vars here -e "location=Huston"

```
    - name: Print
      debug:
        msg:
#          - "{{ wcc.onefs_host }}"
          - "{{ {{location}}.onefs_host }}"
          - "{{ api_user }}"
          - "{{ api_password }}"
```

I am getting the below error.

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: expected token ':', got '}'. String: {{ {{isilon_location}}.onefs_host }}"}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Ansible interpret a variable inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408680/how-can-i-make-ansible-interpret-a-variable-inside-a-variable)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this way

```
- name: Print
  debug:
    msg:
    - "{{ vars[location]['onefs_host'] }}"
    - "{{ api_user }}"
    - "{{ api_password }}"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked.