# Registering service_facts variable in order to use it in a Jinja template

Tags: ansible, jinja2, ansible-template

I'm trying to use `service_facts` to report if a service is in a running state, then email that out via a Jinja template. To grab the service info I'm using the following:

```yaml
- name: get service facts
  service_facts:
  
- name: services check
  debug:
    var: ansible_facts.services['{{ item }}.service'].state
  loop: "{{ server_facts.services|default (servicescheck) }}"
  register: servicestatus
```

which gives me the following:

```json
{
    "ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service'].state": "running",
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false,
    "item": "firewalld",
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "_ansible_item_label": "firewalld"
}
```

and the registered variable looks like:

```json
{
    "msg": [
        {
            "results": [
                {
                    "ansible_facts.services['firewalld.service'].state": "running",
                    "failed": false,
                    "changed": false,
                    "item": "firewalld",
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item"
                },
                {
                    "ansible_facts.services['sshd.service'].state": "running",
                    "failed": false,
                    "changed": false,
                    "item": "sshd",
                    "ansible_loop_var": "item"
                }
            ],
            "msg": "All items completed",
            "changed": false
        }
    ],
    "_ansible_verbose_always": true,
    "_ansible_no_log": false,
    "changed": false
}
```

I'm able to pull out the service name with `servicestatus.results.0.item` in a debug task, and in the Jinja template I'm building out.
However, pulling the service state has be stumped.

I have tried the following without any success:

- `"{{ servicestatus.results.0.ansible_facts.services.state }}"`
- `"{{ ansible_facts.services['{{ server_facts.services }}.service.state'] }}"`

Obviously, I'm pretty clueless on how to pull the service state out of the variable.

The Jinja template looks like this, currently, which fails since the state variable is wrong:

```
Service Checks:
{% for result in servicestatus.results %}
Service: {{ result.item }}
State:   {{ ansible_facts.services['{{ server_facts.services }}.service'].state }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Additionally to the already given answer you may take advantage from [Ansible: How to get disabled but running services?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70376280/6771046).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to have an intermediary variable and surely not to use the result of a `debug` task to do that, your template should be as simple as:

```
Service Checks:
{% for result in server_facts.services | default(servicescheck) %}
Service: {{ result }}
State:   {{ ansible_facts.services[result ~ '.service'].state }} 
{% endfor %}
```

Because, [***‘moustaches don’t stack’***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67408681/2123530).

---

<sub>Regarding the usage of `register` in a `debug` task, this is a non-sense that you should banish from your playbooks.

Registering a variable should be achieved with the [`set_fact` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html).</sub>

Comment: Thank you. I have more reading on dynamic variables now.