# Append a list with loop in Ansible

Tags: python, java, ansible, jinja2

I'm trying to append new tunnel interface to empty list, but I'm getting the below error.

```yaml
- name: empty list
  set_fact:
          list_tunnel: []

- name: create new list for tunnel
  set_fact:
        list_tunnel_new: "{{ list_tunnel + ['tunnel.{{item}}'] }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1,10)|list}}"
```

Error:

> fatal: [SJL]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to be in '/etc/ansible/aws/interface_palo_facts.yaml': line 34, column 12, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n\n         - name: print facts\n           ^ here\n"}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Ansible interpret a variable inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408680/how-can-i-make-ansible-interpret-a-variable-inside-a-variable)

Comment: Also mind that you are getting this error in a task that you are not showing here `- name: print facts`

Comment: And so, your `set_fact` should read `list_tunnel_new: "{{ list_tunnel + ['tunnel.' ~ item] }}"`

Comment: here is the print_facts:

         - name: print facts
           debug:
                  msg: "{{ list_tunnel_new }}"

Comment: also , i tried to use your direction but getting below o/p , looks like it is not appending:

ok: [SJL] => {
    "msg": [
        "tunnel.9"
    ]
}

what i need is : [tunnel.1, tunnel.2, tunnel.3.......,tunnel.9 ]

Comment: Because you made a mess in your variables names: `list_tunnel: "{{ list_tunnel + ['tunnel.' ~ item] }}"`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```yaml
- name: create new list for tunnel
  set_fact:
    list_tunnel: "{{ list_tunnel | default([]) + ['tunnel.' + item | string] }}"
  loop: "{{ range(1,10) | list}}"

- debug:
    msg: "{{ list_tunnel }}"
```

or

```yaml
- set_fact:
    list_tunnel: "{{ result }}"
  vars:
    prefix: tunnel
    a_list: "{{ range(1, 10) | list }}"
    result: "{{ [prefix] | product(a_list) | map('join', '.') | list }}"
```

Comment: How does Ansible works w that 'map(join, .) part? It's so weird to see that. And why is prefix required, why can't we simply put the string 'tunnel' as a string in the result variable.

Answer (score 1):

Create the list you want to add

```yaml
  list_tunnel_add: "{{ ['tunnel']|product(range(1,10))|
                                  map('join','.')|
                                  list }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  list_tunnel_add:
  - tunnel.1
  - tunnel.2
  - tunnel.3
  - tunnel.4
  - tunnel.5
  - tunnel.6
  - tunnel.7
  - tunnel.8
  - tunnel.9
```

Then concatenate the lists

```yaml
  list_tunnel_new: "{{ list_tunel + list_tunnel_add }}"
```

---

Example of a complete playbook

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    list_tunel: []
    list_tunnel_add: "{{ ['tunnel']|product(range(1,10))|
                                    map('join','.')|
                                    list }}"
    list_tunnel_new: "{{ list_tunel + list_tunnel_add }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: list_tunnel_new
```

gives

```yaml
  list_tunnel_new:
  - tunnel.1
  - tunnel.2
  - tunnel.3
  - tunnel.4
  - tunnel.5
  - tunnel.6
  - tunnel.7
  - tunnel.8
  - tunnel.9
```