# Retrieve parameters from AWS SSM with ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-ssm

I need to retrieve some parameters from AWS SSM with ansible to create an env file. I tried this tasks:

```
- name: Get enviroment vars
  local_action:  set_fact "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/myi-homemade-apps-config/{{ service_environment }}/{{ stack_name }}', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true, on_missing='skip' ) }}"


- name: Create .env file
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: env.file.j2
    dest: /opt/docker-swarm-stack/{{ stack_name }}/.env
    mode: "0600"
  become: true
```

I set local_action because I need this task being executed in the local host, not in remote.

The template has:

```
{% for key, value in env_content.items() %}
{{key}}={{value}}
{% endfor %}
```

When I play the playbook, I get this error:

```
fatal: [remote_host -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "template error while templating string: unexpected end of template, expected ','.. String: \"{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/myi-homemade-apps-config/{{ service_environment }}/{{ stack_name }}', region"}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

I tried this task:

```
  local_action:  set_fact "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/myi-homemade-apps-config/{{ service_environment }}/{{ stack_name }}', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true, on_missing='skip' ) }}"
```

Without the {{ before lookup and without the last }} but I get this error:

```
TASK [docker-swarm-stack : Get enviroment vars] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: NoneType: None
fatal: [remote_host -> localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "The variable name '\" lookup('aws_ssm', '/myi-homemade-apps-config/development/service', region' is not valid. Variables must start with a letter or underscore character, and contain only letters, numbers and underscores."}
```

Comment: `'/myi-homemade-apps-config/' ~ service_environment ~ '/' ~ stack_name`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make Ansible interpret a variable inside a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67408680/how-can-i-make-ansible-interpret-a-variable-inside-a-variable)

Comment: I tried: local_action: set_fact "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/myi-homemade-apps-config/' ~ service_environment ~ '/' ~ stack_name ~'/', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true, on_missing='skip' )}} "```` but same error

Comment: I tried to change the variables with the sintaxys in the link you have send me, but same error

Comment: `set_fact` need a variable name, which you failed to provide to the module, so it assumes your value to be the variable name and fails. https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html

Comment: I know it, on first I have this code but also fails:    local_action: set_fact env_content: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/myi-homemade-apps-config/{{ service_environment }}/{{ stack_name }}/', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true, on_missing='skip' )}} "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that set_fact is not being given a parent fact to store all your parameters from SSM.

Here's an updated code that will work for you.

```
- name: Get SSM parameters
  local_action:
    module: ansible.builtin.set_fact
    env_content: "{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/myi-homemade-apps-config/{{ service_environment }}/{{ stack_name }}', region='eu-west-1', shortnames=true, bypath=true, recursive=true, on_missing='skip' ) }}"
      shortnames=true, bypath=true,
      recursive=true) }}"

- name: Create .env file
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: env.file.j2
    dest: /opt/docker-swarm-stack/{{ stack_name }}/.env
    mode: "0600"
  become: true
```

This solution will pull all parameters from SSM that match your path, and store them as directory entries to the `env_content` fact.  Your template is already iterating over the `env_content` to pull the key/value pairs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Hello, I have one more question. If I need to set this parameters as environment for example in ecs definition task, how can I do it? I tried using the env_content variable as a dictionary but doesn't work. Thanks